«Распространяющийся» или «который распространяется»?
Можно ли использовать такой вариант?

Компания ввела запрет на просмотр матчей, распространяющийся на тех
пользователей…

Или все нужно заменить «распространяющийся» на «который распространяется»?

Стремление к усложнению фразы дабы придать ей наукообразности или юридической строгости да еще и впечатлить изяществом речевых оборотов (при недостатке навыков) может привести:

к «случайной двусмысленности» https://avtoram.com/dvusmyslennost/#:~:text=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83,%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0 ;
к смещению акцента с самого важного на второстепенные детали;
к размыванию смысла высказывания вплоть до полной его утраты.

Верные слуги пустословия: «лишнее слово — лишний оборот — избыточный фрагмент».
https://lapsus.timuroki.ink/pest/fragment/
Выводы:

Предложенные в вопросе вариации фразы содержат грубые речевые ошибки.
Если цель высказывания – донести важную информацию до слушателя, то лучше будет выбрать более простой вариант, например:
«Компания запретила просмотр матчей тем пользователям»...


Ответ не по теме. Был задан вопрос об особенностях построения деепричастного оборота и придаточного предложения.

По стилю лучше подходит вариант с придаточным определительным:
Компания ввела запрет на просмотр матчей, который распространяется на тех пользователей…
Пояснение
Это параллельные конструкции по Розенталю, то есть являются взаимозаменяемыми (здесь подходят оба варианта). В то же время существует ряд факторов по которым делается выбор. Тема обсуждалась на форуме, там можно посмотреть характеристику каждого варианта.
В данном случае это книжная деловая речь, а причастные обороты более уместны в художественном или разговорном стиле:
"Причастные обороты воспринимаются как эстетическая категория художественного текста. Они не только образно описывают, характеризуют предмет, но и представляют его признак в динамике, в процессе его становления, развития, изменения. Они соединяют в себе энергию глагола и описательную экспрессию прилагательного".
Соответственно, признаки художественного стиля  в приведенном предложении будут смотреться менее корректно. С другой стороны, причастный оборот более краткая и сжатая форма, это его преимущество.

Спасибо за ответ. Я думал, что здесь больше подходит вариант с использованием «который распространяется» по той причине, что после слова «запрет» идут еще несколько других. То есть, к примеру, «компания установила запрет, распространяющийся…» звучит хорошо, а вот «компания усьановила запрет на просмотр матчей, распространяющийся…» уже почему-то не так. Или мне одному так кажется?

Чем ближе расположен оборот к определяемому слову, тем лучше, в этом вы правы. Но здесь у на два определения: несоглас. определение + придаточное, так что вариант допустимый. Придаточное согласовано с сущ. запрет, поэтому проблем с согласованием нет.

Я думаю, что причастный оборот и придаточное определительное находятся в одинаковых условиях по отношению к определяемому слову. По правилу Розенталя  слова который, какой, чем замещают БЛИЖАЙШЕЕ к ним существительное в форме того же рода и числа. Такое же требование по согласованию предъявляется к причастию. §210. Ошибки в сложных предложениях, пункт 4  https://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/68.htm

Значит, вариант «распространяющийся» в данном случае подходит?

Да, подходит.  У придаточного более строгие правила относительно позиции, а определительные обороты, выраженные прилагательными или причастиями,  тоже чаще находятся непосредственно после определяемого слова, но могут стоять  даже на расстоянии от него. Их связь определяется по согласованию. Вот примеры из Розенталя:  Цвет небосклона, лёгкий, бледно-лиловый, не изменяется во весь день. В утренней прохладе разлит горький запах полыни, смешанный с нежным, похожим на миндаль, ароматом повилики (Купр.).


если оторвано в тексте от существительного: Глаза смыкались и, полузакрытые, тоже улыбались (Т.); На лавке, разбросанные, лежали поршни, ружьё (Л. Т.);


У меня тогда дополнительный вопрос: зачем вообще нужен канцелярский или деловой стили речи — информативный куда лучше!  Давайте все законы перепишем заново, чтобы  донести важную информацию до слушателя.
Для этого открываем книгу: Максим Ильяхов "Пиши, сокращай", и там изложены все приемы информативного стиля.  Особому гонению подвергаются причастные обороты, определительные предложения с союзным словом который, отглагольные существительные и местоимения.  Главное — информация, а иначе читать не будут.
С другой стороны, есть другие стили: художественный, деловой, публицистический. И всегда нужен контекст, прежде чем предлагать правку.
И вопросы на форуме нужно задавать корректно, например: (1) Как лучше записать предложение? (2) Каковы особенности грамматики причастного оборота и придаточного определительного предложения?
А то мы даем два ответа к разным вопросам: особенности информативного стиля и синтаксическая синонимия.
Вот что забавно! Полезны вроде бы оба ответа, то в смешанном виде выглядят странно. Александр Пушкин.
 Глухой глухого звал к суду судьи глухого,
 Глухой кричал: "Моя им сведена корова!"-
 "Помилуй, — возопил глухой тому в ответ: -
 Сей пустошью владел еще покойный дед".
 Судья решил: "Чтоб не было разврата,
 Жените молодца, хоть девка виновата".


Всё это придумали мы для того, чтобы как можно более придать разнообразия прогулкам. [И. А. Гончаров. Лихая болесть (1838)] ///////////////////
— Я все слышал, — бросил Натан, серый, какой-то обескровленный; даже кромешный семейный скандал уже не мог встряхнуть его, не мог придать ни капли энергии, возмущения или боли. [Дина Рубина. Русская канарейка. Блудный сын (2014)]
